# When would you INNER JOIN a LEFT JOINed table /

Tags: sql, sql-server

I came across below code today.

```
SELECT StaffGroup.*
FROM StaffGroup
LEFT OUTER JOIN StaffByGroup 
  ON StaffByGroup.StaffGroupId = StaffGroup.StaffGroupId
INNER JOIN StaffMember 
   ON StaffMember.StaffMemberId = StaffByGroup.StaffMemberId
WHERE StaffByGroup.StaffGroupId IS NULL
```

The main table `StaffGroup` is being LEFT JOINed with `StaffByGroup` table and then `StaffByGroup` table is being INNER JOINed with `StaffMember` table.

I thought the INNER JOIN is trying to filter out the records which exist in `StaffGroup` and `StaffByGroup` but do not exist in `StaffMember`.

But this is not how it is working. The query does not return any records.

Am I missing something in understanding the logic of the query ? Have you ever used INNER JOIN with a table which has been used with LEFT JOIN in earlier part of the query ?

Comment: If you remove the `where` clause, does it return records?

Comment: Yes. If I remove the WHERE clause, it returns the records which exist in all three tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query looks fundamentally flawed - I guess what was originally intended is

```
SELECT StaffGroup.*
FROM StaffGroup
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM StaffByGroup 
   INNER JOIN StaffMember 
   ON StaffMember.StaffMemberId = StaffByGroup.StaffMemberId) StaffByGroup
ON StaffByGroup.StaffGroupId = StaffGroup.StaffGroupId
WHERE StaffByGroup.StaffGroupId IS NULL
```

which returns all groups from StaffGroup that dont' have existing staffmembers assigned to them (the INNER JOIN with StaffMember filters out those rows from StaffByGroup that don't have a matching row in StaffMember - probably because there exists no foreign key between them)

Comment: I don't think this is somehow different from original query. And it is not returning results because there is no records `WHERE StaffByGroup.StaffGroupId IS NULL`

Comment: @VitaliyG This is *very* different from the original query. The original query *cannot* return any results because the inner join allows only results with a matching row in StaffMember/StaffByGroup, and those rows are then removed by the WHERE clause. My modified query first returns *all* rows from StaffGroup plus optional values for StaffByGroup/StaffMember and subsequently removes those rows that didn't have a matching StaffMember/StaffByGroup.

Comment: Yes you are correct. What do you think, maybe StaffMember can be simply left joined instead of using sub select.

Comment: That wouldn't return the same result - if you left join StaffMember, the query without the WHERE clause will return a StaffGroupID for StaffGroups without members; therefore, these groups will be removed by the final WHERE clause. If that is intended, you can get rid of the JOIN with StaffMember, since it's completely superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are missing one concept:
The main table `StaffGroup` is being `LEFT Joined` with `StaffByGroup` table and then this creates a `virtual table` say `VT1` with all records from StaffGroup and matching records from StaffByGroup based on your match/filter condition in `ON` predicate.Then not StaffByGroup table but this `VT1` is being `INNER Joined` with `StaffMember` table based on match/filter condition in `ON` predicate.
So basically the inner join is trying to filter out those records from StaffGroup and hence StaffByGroup which do not have a StaffMemberId.
Adding your where condition adds a final filter like from the final virtual table created by all the above joins remove all such records which don't have a StaffGroupId which in turn might be removing all rows collected in `VT1` as all of them will be having some value for StaffGroupId.

To get all records from StaffGroup which have no StaffGroupId along with details from StaffMember for all such records you can add condition in ON predicate as:

```
SELECT StaffGroup.*
FROM StaffGroup
LEFT OUTER JOIN StaffByGroup 
  ON StaffByGroup.StaffGroupId = StaffGroup.StaffGroupId and StaffByGroup.StaffGroupId IS NULL
INNER JOIN StaffMember 
   ON StaffMember.StaffMemberId = StaffByGroup.StaffMemberId
```

Comment: Would it be safe to say that the query is wrong and needs correction ? Actually this is existing code and I am reverse engineering it.

Comment: That actually depends on what is the exact requirement that you have. I have suggested a sample scenario. Hope that helps.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting 0 records because of your `where clause`

```
where StaffByGroup.StaffGroupId is null
```

The `left join`  links all the records from tbl A which are contained in tbl B and since you have specified `StaffGROUPID` as your key and then looked for `Nulls` values in your key, its 100% clear that you will end up with no results